# Не работает appendChild

Tags: javascript

Ошибка app4.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: sectionImg.appendChild is not a function

```js
let sectionImg = document.getElementsByClassName('imgSection');
let image = document.createElement('img');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

image.setAttribute('src','img/' + getRandomInt(1,9) + '.png');

sectionImg.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Понял,спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName возвращает HTMLCollection, у него нет свойства appendChild.
HTMLCollection - это как массив, но его нельзя просто так перебрать, для этого нужно превратить его в массив.

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('imgSection')].forEach(element=>{element.appendChild(image)})
```